# Meta Refresh for Safari

Tags: asp.net, safari, refresh, meta-tags, page-refresh

I used meta refresh but it doesn't work 'Safari'. What can i do?

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL='http://example.com/'">
```

Answer (score 2):

According to what I found on Google; this may have been a bug in Safari in the past but many people claim it's been resolved.

There's also [someone](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/archive/index.php/t-43535.html) mentioning that it could be that this specific header is disabled in Safari.

If none of the above works, you can always use javascript to do the redirection:

```
function redirect()
{
    setTimeout(function(){window.location='otherpage.html'},5000);//5 secs
}

window.onload=redirect;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported by Safari.. And your not the only one who asked that..
There is 2 possibility:

1. Make a button to let user refresh the page
2. Use Ajax to be able to update parts of your website

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response, i chose first one.

Comment: Your welcome, Safari blocks it now and if you want to authorize redirects in your safari client you have to Turn on cookies in the Security preferences and delete cookies already there related to the website. So you are better with the button of course!