# Safari doesn't support refresh content

Tags: html, safari, refresh

I'm using this code

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30" />
```

To update iframe content. But Safari won't support this. Is there are other code that both Chrome, Safari and Firefox supports, and does the same functionality?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12181682),

> This may have been a bug in Safari in the past but many people claim it's been resolved.
>   There's also [someone](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/archive/index.php/t-43535.html) mentioning that it could be that this specific header is disabled in Safari.

But you can still :

1. Make a button to let user refresh the page
2. Use a setInterval() to update it in JavaScript

   ```
   setInterval(function() {}, duration);
   ```